# Giving me an error when i want to Display my GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to create a GUI but when I click run it gives me an error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
public class GUIsetup {
    private Frame guiFrame;
    private Panel pTop ,pMid,pBot;
    private Button bSave,bClear,bExit;
    private TextField tSN,tFN,tLN,tP,tQ1,tQ2;
    private JLabel hack;

    public void GUIsetup(){
            guiFrame=new Frame("Hackethon Event Regeestrasion App Version 1.0" );
            pTop=new Panel();
            pMid=new Panel();
            pBot=new Panel();
            bSave=new Button("Save");
            bClear=new Button("Clear");
            bExit=new Button("Exit");
            tSN=new TextField();
            tFN=new TextField();
            tLN=new TextField();
            tP=new TextField();
            tQ1=new TextField();
            tQ2=new TextField();
            hack=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Hacker.png"));
     }

     public void setGUI(){
            pTop.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
            pBot.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,3));
            pMid.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        
            pTop.add(hack);
        
            pMid.add(tSN);
            pMid.add(tFN);
            pMid.add(tLN);
            pMid.add(tP);
            pMid.add(tQ1);
            pMid.add(tQ2);
        
            pBot.add(bSave);
            pBot.add(bSave);
            pBot.add(bSave);
        
            guiFrame.add(pTop,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            guiFrame.add(pMid,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            guiFrame.add(pBot,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
            guiFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
                    
           guiFrame.setSize(400, 400);
           guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But when I run the `setGUI` method it gives me the error on the first line of the method where I declare the grid layout

Comment: Did you mean `public GUIsetup()` instead of `public void GUIsetup()`? I assume you wanted to create a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove the `void` in

```
public void GUIsetup()
```

As it is right now, it is considered a normal method and Java doesn't recognise it as the constructor. So calling `new GUIsetup()` will call the generated "default" constructor (which is empty of course). Thus, no variables are initialised and calling `setGui()` will hit null when trying to work on `pTop`.

```
public GUIsetup(){
```

This is what your constructor should look like.